# Wordpress include meta tag in theme header on a custom template page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a template page I have created myself. On it, I add the header used in the WordPress theme using:

```
get_header();
```

However, in it, only on this page, I need to add HTML  tag. If I add it after the above code, it is not in the  section. I do not want to add it to the theme's header, because, as I explained, I do not need this meta tag on other pages. Also, I do not want to copy the whole header in my template's file, as this is duplicate code and it doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the changes in your header.php by using conditional tags.

For example, in your header.php, add something like this:

```
<?php
    if (is_page_template( 'templates/YOUR_PAGE_TEMPLATE.php' ) ):
        //Your code goes here
    endif;
?>
```

You can use [other conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to suit your needs.